# Android: How to remove customize keyboard button from keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

Please find below the screenshot wherein the circular box shows the customize button option.

[image]

XMl Code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_cost_per_mile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Cost Per Mile(₤)"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
/>
```

All I want to remove :: button from keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, but you do not have direct control over what an input method editor offers to its users.

Comment: I think what you can do is to create a custom keyboard so you will have the keyboard you want? http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

Comment: share your custom-keyboard code

Answer (score 0):

You have change input type like..

```
 android:inputType="phone"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not. This is your android keyboard app and you cant change it. The keyboard settings can be modified in the android settings. But obviously it depends on the user, not the developer.

The only way I think it will allow you to do that is that you include in your app a fake numeric keypad as a layer (Similar to the keyboard that appears when you have to type the pin of the app of your bank). However, I don't think this is worth it. With...

```
android:inputType = "numberSigned"
```

you are already blocking the user from entering letters or other characters, even if they change their keyboard.